# Merging elements in a collection that satisfy a predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm wondering if there is an algorithm to merge elements in a collection that satisfy a predicate
Something like the following code:

```cpp
struct Element
{
  int size;
  constexpr static int maxSize = 150;
  enum Type { Mergeable, notMergeable } type;
};

auto predicate = [](const Element& el1, const Element& el2)
{
  //Done by the algorithm

  if(&el1 == &el2) // An element should not merge with itself obviously
    return false;

  if(el1.size == 0 || el2.size == 0) //element is marked for deletion
    return false; 

  //User predicate:
  bool isBelowMaxSize = el1.size + el2.size < Element::maxSize;
  bool isMergeable = el1.type  == Element::Type::Mergeable  && el2.type  == Element::Type::Mergeable;

  return isBelowMaxSize && isMergeable;
}

//User merge function
auto merge = [](Element& el1, Element& el2)
{
  el1 += el2;

  //Done by the algorithm
  el2.size = 0; //Marks for deletion
}

int main()
  std::vector<Element> els;
  //Let's assume els contains elements
  for(auto& el1 : els)
      for(auto& el2 : els)
          if(predicate(el1, el2))
            merge(el1, el2)

  //Merged elements are now removed
}
```

I thought I could do the same with ranges:

```cpp
    namespace rv = ranges::views;
    auto result = rv::cartesian_product(els, els) | rv::filter(predicate) | rv::for_each(merge);
```

But I'm afraid it would not work correctly, since it could try to merge elements that have already been merged.

So, is there a clean way to do it?

Comment: What's the desired outcome? Merge as many elements as possible? Find the "best" merges?

Comment: @Caleth Good question. The desired outcome it to merge as many elements as possible.

Comment: That sounds like the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: "_Identical elements are not merged_" - But you don't mind more than two elements being merged into one? If so, two elements that are identical in the first pass may not be identical in the next pass and then be merged, so what's the point of restricting identical elements from being merged?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's an error on my wording, my bad. I meant that element with the same index do not get merged. vec[0] will not be merged with vec[0]

Comment: @Caleth Indeed, it may help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Useless, @Ted Lyngmo and @Caleth, here is my answer

```cpp
//Expects a range sorted in descending order
template<class It, class Predicate, class Sum>
[[nodiscard]] static It merge_if(It first, It last, Predicate predicate, Sum sum)
{
    assert(first != last);
    last--;

    while (first != last)
    {
        while (predicate(*first, *last))
        {
            *first = sum(*first, *last);
            last--;
        }
        first++;
    }
    first++;
    return first; //One past the end
}

template<class It, class Predicate>
[[nodiscard]] static It merge_if(It first, It last, Predicate predicate)
{
    using Type = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)>>;
    auto plus = [](const Type &first, const Type &second) { return first + second; };
    return merge_if(first, last, predicate, plus);
}
```

Some test cases are available on [my GitLab](https://gitlab.com/G_ka/playground)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* complexity by first filtering all `Element::Type::Mergeable` items with `size < Element::maxSize` into a separate container (which is *O(n)*), and sorting it by size (which is *O(n log n)*).

With a sorted container of candidates, you can easily walk it from both ends until your iterators meet in the middle. Combining the largest and smallest elements will give all permissible merges in linear time.

Comment: Thanks. However, now that I think about it, after the merge, there still may be possible merges. The results may be once again mergeable

Comment: @G'k With this algorithm, if for example sorted in decending order: `while(begin!=end) {` Create a bin and put `*begin` (the largest element) in it. Fill that `begin` bin with `*end` values (the smallest values) decreasing `end` as you go, until the `begin` bin is full (or `begin==end` then break), then increase `begin` and  `}`  - A second pass should not result in any merges being possible.

Comment: @G'k You can use `std::partition` to do the filtering so you get the mergable elements in one range and the rest in the other range and then `std::sort` the range you are going to do the merging on.